# Javascript Array with Dynamic Editable Objects and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to track cars and car types/colors without a database and I'm looking for a way to create an array with objects that I can update and delete, then be able to call the array.

So maybe something like this where I can add/edit/delete any of the object properties by car:

```
let cars = [];
cars['ferrari'] = "red";
cars["lambo"] = "white";
cars["bentley"] = "silver";
```

I know how to get the value with this example:

```
showcolor = 'ferrari';
alert(cars[showcolor]);
```

Is it possible to push a new object into this array and/or update a single car and change the color for that car with a function that looks for the object value 'ferrari' and changes its color to 'black'? Also if I wanted to create an alert to show the contents of the array, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you considered using a Map? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use an array, but let each element of the array be an object.

```
let cars = [];
cars.push({ make: 'ferrari', color: 'red' });
cars.push({ make: 'lambo', color: 'white' });
cars.push({ make: 'bentley', color: 'silver' });
console.log(JSON.stringify(cars));

// Make the lambo black instead of white.
cars.find(car => car.make == 'lambo').color = 'black';
console.log(JSON.stringify(cars));
```

Output is:

```
[{"make":"ferrari","color":"red"},{"make":"lambo","color":"white"},{"make":"bentley","color":"silver"}]
[{"make":"ferrari","color":"red"},{"make":"lambo","color":"black"},{"make":"bentley","color":"silver"}]
```

Note the lambo color changed.

Comment: Or an object of objects where key is the make. So you can access car properties like `cars['ferrarri']['color']`.

Comment: This is rock solid. No doubt there are a few ways to do this and I'm appreciative of everyone's effort. This will definitely help me with the cars. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an array. Use an [object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp):

```js
let cars = {}; // {} creates a new object

cars['ferrari'] = "red";
cars["lambo"] = "white";
cars["bentley"] = "silver";

// add new car
cars['bugatti'] = 'blue';

// update car
cars['lambo'] = 'green'

console.log(cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Map from ES20015  standart.
let cars = new Map([
    ['ferrari',   'red'],
    ['lambo', 'white'],
    ['bentley',   'silver']
]);
```

`console.log(cars.get('ferrari')) // red`

You can also add car:
`cars.set('bmw','black');`

`console.log(cars.get('bmw')) // black`

For updating:
`cars.set('bmw','blue')`;

Use `for ... of` for alerts data:

`for(let car of cars) {
      alert(car);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Use object oriented JavaScript

```
class Cars{
  constructor(color) {
    this.color= color;
  }
  function getColor(){
    console.log(this.color);
  }
```

Then create an instant of it

```
var mycar = new Cars('Blue');
mycar.getColor();
```